# Find circumradius of $\Delta DEC$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

$A(0,0),B(4,0)$ and $C(5,-2\sqrt 6)$ are the vertices of $\Delta ABC$. Incircle of the triangle touches side $AC$ and $BC$ at $D$ and $E$ respectively. Find the circumradius of the triangle $DEC$. Is there a short way using analytical geometry? Calculating the coordinates of $D$ and $E$ using section formula gives quite nasty coordinates. What do I do? Thanks.

Comment: you can use that $$R=\frac{abc}{4A}$$

Comment: Yeah, do you think a,b,c are easy to calculate. Let alone the area.

Comment: the area is given by the formula of Heron

Comment: i mean the triangle $\Delta DEC$

Comment: But you dont know the sides if the triangle. That is what i am trying to say.

Comment: without knowing the sides of this triangle you can't calculate $R$

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I dont think you are getting the question. I know the three coordinates of the triangle. This means i know the sides of the trianlge. But the thing is that the coordinates are nasty and the method is quite tedious as well. I am looking for a better approach.

Comment: i have got the question very well i think a better approach doesn't exist